# this.$router.push is causing a leaveGuards.forEach is not a function error

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router4

I am using Vue3 and Vue router 4, while tyring to run this.$router.push
it throws `leaveGuards.forEach is not a function`

I see that https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/f776cbe1098596f53b5c2f696d29e1c02afd1fc1/packages/router/src/router.ts#L824 at this particular line for my application the leaveGuards is an empty object. Why is that? How can I resolve my error?

I tried

```js
this.$router.push({
path: //
query: //
})
```

And router.js seems to be configured properly

Comment: router.push under normal circumstances works just fine.  It's not known what circumstances exist in your app to produce this error.  you should include all relevant router code so we can maybe figure out how and why this happens.